# Finding UMVUE of parameter $\displaystyle a^{-\theta}$, $(0<a<1)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, umvue

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample of $\operatorname{Beta}(\theta,1)$. How can I find UMVUE  of parameter $\displaystyle a^{\theta}$, $(0<a<1)$?

Comment: Is this for some course?

Answer (score 2):

These will be your steps

1. Find a complete and suﬃcient statistic for $\theta$

2. Find a function of this statistic that is unbiased for $a^\theta$

What have you done so far?